# Need to redirect outgoing local SMTP emails to localhost within Windows

Tags: windows, email, redirect, smtp, port

I am wondering if it is possible to intercept outgoing SMTP emails on a Windows 7 VM developing machine to localhost on the same machine.  I need the ability to create a dummy localhost mail server on the same VM where I can create an infinite amount of email accounts.  I need to do QA testing on an application without re-configuring it's SMTP setup to no longer use Port 25.  For security reasons the email ports are all closed so hoping for this solution.  I see there are ways to do this with Linux easily with iptables and hoping for a solution that will work for Window 7.
Thanks,